# Bootstrap Overlapping Issue

Tags: html, css

Bootstrap Overlapping Issue

Whenever I resize my website into a smaller size, I get the issue of the inner div elements overlapping other div elements. I have pictures of the website for you guys to see before and after regarding this.

Before resizing:

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

My CSS code:

```
#logo{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
#titleImage{
    height: 900px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: grayscale(30%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);   
}
#logo img{
     -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1));
       -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#000000')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#000000')";
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
@font-face{
    font-family: "comicF";
    src: url(../font/Kaushan.otf) format('truetype');
}
#navbar a{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    font-family: comicF;
    display: inline;
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 5px white;
    padding-right: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-change {
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    background: #000;
    height: 90px;
}
#about{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;   
    background-size: cover;
    filter: grayscale(40%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
   }
#about div{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-family: normalA;
    font-size: 30px; 
    background-color: rgba(60, 54, 53, .3);
    height: 100%;
}
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
#about h1{    
    padding-top: 65px;
    color: #FAE9C4;
    font-size: 99px;
}
#about p{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;  
    font-family: normalA;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}
#line1 {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: 70%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(75,63,54, 0), rgba(75,63,54, 0.75), rgba(75,63,54, 0));
}
#team{
    padding-top: 25px;
    background-color:  white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 660px;
    text-align: center;
}
#team p{
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: normal;
}
#team h{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    /*    color: #3C3635;*/
    font-family: comicC;
}
.teamDiv{
    padding-top: 35px;
    border-radius: 25%; 
    text-align: center;     
}
#infoGeneral{
    padding-top: 30px;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 280px;
    /*    background-color:  #3C3635; */
    background-color:    #4D3F36;
    /*    #4b433b*/
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 4px #FAE9C4 solid;
    filter: grayscale(20%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(20%); 
}
#infoGeneral p{
    font-family: normal;
    border-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#infoGeneral p:first-of-type{
    padding-top: 9px;
}
.underScoreInfoGeneral{
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FAE9C4;
    width: 70px;
    height: 4px;
}
.socialIcons{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#map { //gogle maps
       width: 100%;
       height: 350px;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #3C3635;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>About</title>
        <link href="css/aboutCSS.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="titleImage" style="background-image: url(img/coffeee.jpg);">
                <div class="row">                
                    <div id="logo" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><img src="img/logo_white.png" style="width:40%;" alt="Mountain View"></div>                               
                    <span style="font-size:2.5em; color: white; text-align: right;"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil col-md-1 col-md-offset-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>        
                </div>  <!-- 1row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="navbar" class="col-md-12">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.jsp">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="shop.jsp">Shop</a></li>
                        </ul><!-- NAVBAR-->
                    </div><!-- row -->
                </div> 
            </div>
            <!--  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
            <div class="row" style="background-color: white; height: 300px;">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="about" style="background-image: url(img/coffee-beans.jpg);"><div><h1 style="font-family: comicF; font-size: 50px;">Lorem totem</h1>
                        <p>rem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div></div>  
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="team">
                    <h1 style="font-family: impactA; font-size: 45px; color: #4C3F37;">Our amazing team</h1><hr id="line1"/>
                    <div class="col-md-4 teamDiv" ><img src="img/woman3.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="" style="width:30%;">
                        <p style="font-size: 340%; padding-top: 15px; font-family: comicC; margin-bottom: 0px;">Lucy Luu</p ><p style="color: #4b433b;">Marketing Director</p>
                        <div class="socialIcons"><img src="img/facebook3.png" alt="" style="width:7%;">
                            <img src="img/twitter3.png" alt="" style="width:7%;">
                            <img src="img/linkedin3.png" alt="" style="width:7%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 teamDiv"><img src="img/woman4.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="" style="width:30%;">
                        <p style="font-size: 340%; padding-top: 15px; font-family: comicC; margin-bottom: 0px;">Melissa Gunson</p ><p style="color: #4b433b;">Founder</p>
                        <div class="socialIcons">     <img src="img/facebook3.png" alt="" style="width:7%;">
                            <img src="img/twitter3.png" alt="" style="width:7%;">
                            <img src="img/linkedin3.png" alt="" style="width:7%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 teamDiv"><img src="img/man1.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="" style="width:30%;">
                        <p style="font-size: 340%;  padding-top: 15px; font-family: comicC; margin-bottom: 0px;">James Hutson</p><p style="color: #4b433b;">Store Manager</p>
                        <div class="socialIcons"><img src="img/facebook3.png" alt="" style="width:7%;">
                            <img src="img/twitter3.png" alt="" style="width:7%;">
                            <img src="img/linkedin3.png" alt="" style="width:7%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div id="infoGeneral">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div><img src="img/Bhome.png" alt="" style="width:60px; text-align: center;"></div>
                        <h1 style="color: white; font-family: comicF; font-size: 43px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Location</h1>
                        <p>252 E Market St</p>
                        <p>Louisville, KY 40202</p>
                        <div class="underScoreInfoGeneral"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div><img src="img/Bdata.png" alt="" style="width:60px; text-align: center;"></div>         
                        <h2 style="color: white; font-family: comicF; font-size: 43px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Opening Times</h2>
                        <p>Monday - Saturday: 8:00 - 21:00</p>
                        <p>Sunday: closed</p>
                        <div class="underScoreInfoGeneral"></div>                
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div><img src="img/Bworldwide.png" alt="" style="width:60px; text-align: center;"></div>         
                        <h2 style="color: white; font-family: comicF; font-size: 43px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Contact</h2>
                        <p><img src="img/letter106.png" alt="" style="width:25px; padding-right: 4px;"> jameshutson@gmail.com</p>
                        <p><img src="img/telephone5.png" alt="" style="width:25px; padding-right: 4px;"> 502 936 7664</p>
                        <div class="underScoreInfoGeneral"></div>                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" id="map"></div>            
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- container-->
        <script src="js/map.js"></script>   
        <script src="js/navbar.js"></script>          
    </body>
</html>
```

I am assuming thats because I have fixed pixel numbers for paddings and background divs. But I don't know ways around this issue if I want to place certain divs in exact positions of my liking.
I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: You can use `@media` queries to exactly position elements, and change that to some other exact positioning if the screen is a certain size. This way you can specify positioning in pixels for mobiles, tablets and computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove height attribute from #infoGeneral in your CSS. From the looks of your screenshots, your sections are not overlapping, but your CSS is cutting off the content. You have a lot of fixed heights on your DIVs, but your content appears to be higher, and so is being cut off. If you remove the fixed heights, then it should flow better

Answer (score 0):

What kind of layout are you trying to achieve, rigid or fluid? If you are concerned about divs being in exact places then using em sounds like your solution. 
For Example

`#about p{
    padding-left: 10em;
    padding-right: 10em;

    font-family: normalA;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}`

This will allow for your divs to be more dynamic depending on the size of the window, also setting minimum widths would keep from div content overflowing, else you could set overflow to hidden and it would disappear or set it to scroll which would force users to scroll to see the rest of the content but would allow you to have a greater control on how things get placed.

Comment: Fluid. I changed everything to em and still didn't work. Do you know if there is another way to do it?

Comment: it will get more complicated but adding z-indexs to elements will force them to stack in a certain order but if you haven't used z-index before you have to add this property to your divs position: absolute ( or you can set it to fixed, or relative) in your css, depending on your preference.
     I made a site a few years back that may help you. Here's a drop box link, just download and unzip. https://www.dropbox.com/s/atkz8qqicf2memf/FINAL-2015-12-07.zip?dl=0